# I am trying to connect SQL Server(on-premises) from my Azure Function with windows authentication

Tags: .net, sql-server, azure, azure-functions, windows-authentication

I have SQL servers on-prem which only uses windows authentication for login.

I have VPN tunnel setup between my on-prem network and Azure virtual network.

I have an Azure function that needs to get some data from on-prem DB. When I try to connect to SQL server it gives following error:

```
Exception while executing function: FuncPushDataToAzure <--- Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication.
```

Azure functions are deployed in premium app service plan and are able to connect to SQL server. Problem arises when at authentication.

Comment: Switch to SQL Authentication. Windows Authentication is Kerberos, there's no Kerberos in the cloud.

Comment: Is there anything else which I can use? I can't send user name and password in the connection string. Using SQL authentication requires you to send username and password.

Comment: Why is that a concern? It's sent over encrypted transport, be that Hybrid Connections (TLS) or Site to Site VPN (IPsec or SSTP).

Comment: InfoSec of enterprise I am working for does not approve that.

Comment: What is the solution of or alternative to connecting on-prem SQL DB from Azure Functions? Or using other Azure services?

Answer (score 0):

As evilSnobu said Windows Authentication is Kerberos, there's no Kerberos in the cloud, You can not connect SQL Server(on-premises) from my Azure Function with windows authentication.

There isn't a way can help you do that for now.

Hope this helps.

Comment: What is the solution of or alternative to connecting on-prem SQL DB from Azure Functions? Or using other Azure services?

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to install the [on-premise data gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/analysis-services/analysis-services-gateway)

you could easily design a logic app, that fetches the data using the gateway.

You can also use azure functions together with logic apps.

But You can't directly access On-Prem SQL server directly from Azure function - you must use one of the supported cloud services - eg. Logic apps.

Comment: do you mean using Logic apps to connect to on-prem SQL db without using user name and password in connection string? How is it possible?